# Issue installing Tax4Fun

Tags: installation, package

I'm trying to install the package "Tax4Fun" but keep failing.

I've tried 2 different ways:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_url("http://tax4fun.gobics.de/Tax4Fun/Tax4Fun_0.3.1.tar.gz")
library(Tax4Fun)
```

The error that I get is:

```
ERROR: dependency 'biom' is not available for package 'Tax4Fun'
```

I've also tried installing biom directly

```
BiocManager::install("biom")
```

which does not work either

```
Bioconductor version 3.10 (BiocManager 1.30.10), R 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Installing package(s) 'biom'
Installation path not writeable, unable to update packages: boot, foreign, KernSmooth,
  mgcv, nlme, survival
Warning message:
package ‘biom’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)
```

The other way I've tried to install Tax4Fun directly is

```
BiocManager::install("Tax4Fun")
```

I get the following error code:

```
Bioconductor version 3.10 (BiocManager 1.30.10), R 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Installing package(s) 'Tax4Fun'
Installation path not writeable, unable to update packages: boot, foreign, KernSmooth,
  mgcv, nlme, survival
Warning message:
package ‘Tax4Fun’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install it by downloading the packages from source (http://tax4fun.gobics.de). Then it depends whether you are running on Linux/Mac or Windows.
From the command line, you navigate to the folder containing the .tar.gz downloaded package. Then you should install it using:

`R CMD INSTALL Tax4Fun_0.3.1.tar.gz`

But dependancies are not installed by default. So you need to install dependancies manually, **Qiimer** and **Biom**, which are both deprecated on Cran. You install them using the same command, after you have downloaded the packages from the Cran archives.

Before that, you need to also install their dependancies in R:

`install.packages("pheatmap")`

`install.packages("RJSONIO")`

Then you should be able to proceed as mentioned above: install **Qiimer** and **Biom** from the command line first. Then **Tax4Fun** from the command line too.

If you are running on Windows you should have quite the same issues, but the installation of the different packages and dependancies is different. You can have a look at the readme at http://tax4fun.gobics.de